# List as a part of a dictionary in another list does't work properly

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python.
I have faced the trouble: a list of data (3 int var) as part of dictionary in another list(big) behave lake it is the same object for al members of list(big). If I am changing one element in the list(small) and all of the rest the same elements in other lists(small) in other dictioanries are changing as well.
But if I am doing the same in a pure study code everything is working properly.

```
#IT DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY
contr_player_index = current_player['index']
for i in range(0, players_qty-1) :
        contr_player_index = rotate_int(contr_player_index, 0, players_qty-1, 'left')
        contr_player = players_parametrs_list[contr_player_index]
        while True :
            tmp_val = input('Введите значение ВИСТОВ у игрока ' + str(current_player['name']) + ' на игрока ' + str(contr_player['name']) + ': ')
            if is_int(tmp_val) :
                current_player['vst'][i] = int(tmp_val)
                break
            print(err_msg_2)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum runnable example as per these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
From what you show, it is impossible to understand what is happening. My best guess given your description is that your big list points to the same instance of the small list over and over again which would explain the behaviour that you describe. But without a runnable example of your code, it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, your issue is that when you change an item in list A, items in list B also change. This is a classic Python beginner pitfall, an example of this being:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a
b[0] = 2 # change first element to 2
print(a)
# >>> [2, 2, 3, 4]
```

If this is the way you're creating your lists, and you want to avoid this happening, here is a solution:

```py
# A way to avoid this:
import copy
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = copy.deepcopy(a) # creates a "deep" copy, not related to list "a" at all.
b[0] = 2 # change first element to 2
print(a)
print(b)
# >>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
# >>> [2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works! The trouble is solved with copy.deepcopy()

Comment: Great! If this works as a solution to your problem you can click the "Accept this answer" button on my post to close this thread.